# imshow() with desired framerate with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Is there any workaround how to use `cv2.imshow()` with a specific framerate? Im capturing the video via VideoCapture and doing some easy postprocessing on them (both in a separeted thread, so it loads all frames in Queue and the main thread isn't slowed by the computation). I tryed to fix the framerate by calculating the time used for "reading" the image from the queue and then substract that value from number of miliseconds avalible for one frame:
if I have as input video with 50FPS and i want to playback it in real-time i do 1000/50 => 20ms per frame. 
And then wait that time using cv2.WaitKey()
But still I get some laggy output. Which is slower then the source video

Comment: Synchronize it  with the real time clock. Store the current time at the point when you being showing the frames -- let's call that `t0`. Now based on this, you know that frame `N` will need to be shown at time `t0 + N * (1 / FPS)` (in your case `t0 + N * 0.02`). After you fetch the frame and `imshow` it, take the difference between current time and the time the next frame should be displayed (If it's negative, just skip the frame). Trouble with `waitKey` on some platforms is that the granularity of the timer used to wait is pretty large -- e.g. on windows it's about 15ms.

Comment: I did as you sad. It worked, only thning that makes me sad is, that the video on same framerate (not many frames are thown away) looks much more laggy then when i playback it with VLC or other software. Is it because theese programs use some sort of workaround so that their video on same framerate is looking more smooth? Im thinking about some sort of overlaping two images so that thay look more smooth with human eay

Comment: I haven't studied the implementation of VLC or other media players, but I'd bet that there's plenty of stuff designed specifically to play videos smoothly. The HighGUI OpenCV module is primarily intended for convenience, so you can display intermediate results when prototyping. (For my production code using OpenCV I generally have my own visualization/GUI code). Probably some filtering... one problem comes to mind: how do you smoothly display a 50 FPS video on a 60 FPS screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is such a function in opencv but maybe you could improve your method by adding a dynamic wait time using timers? `timeit.default_timer()`
calculate the time taken to process and subtract that from the expected framerate and maybe add a few ms buffer.

eg `cv2.WaitKey((1000/50) - (time processing finished - time read started) - 10)`

or you could have a more rigid timing eg `script start time + frame# * 20ms - time processing finished`

I haven't tried this personally so im not sure if it will actually work, also might be worth having a check so the number isnt below 1

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same video in one of my project in which my source video have 2 fps. so in order to show it in good manners using cv2.imshow I used a delay function before displaying of frame. Its a kind of hack but this thing work for me. The code for this hack is given below. Hope you will get some help from it. peace!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture (0)

width = 400
height = 350

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (width, height))
    flipped = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    framerot = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
    framerot = cv2.resize(framerot, (width, height))
    StackImg = np.hstack([frame, flipped, framerot])
    #Put time of sleep according to your fps
    time.sleep(2)
    cv2.imshow("ImageStacked", StackImg)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```